# When is IWizard.canFinish executed

Tags: java, jface

I have overridden the `canFinish()` method of `IWizard`. The API can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FINewWizard.html)

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean canFinish(){
    if(templatePage.isPageComplete() 
            && jenkinsPage.isPageComplete()
            && containerPage.isPageComplete()
            && dataSourcePage.isPageComplete()
            && queuePage.isPageComplete()
            && deploymentPage.isPageComplete()){
        return true;
    }
    else if(model.isDeployOnly()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

There are other methods like `addPages()` that are also executed. 
Really, I want to know when `canFinish()` is executed? And is there a list of the order in which they are executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`canFinish` is called by the `WizardDialog` whenever it needs to update the buttons on the button bar (the Back, Next and Finish button). There will be calls when the wizard is first shown and when you move between pages. Individual wizards can also call `IWizardContainer.updateButtons` whenever they want the button status updated.

Note: the default code for `canFinish` is:

```
public boolean canFinish() {
    // Default implementation is to check if all pages are complete.
    for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
        if (!pages.get(i).isPageComplete()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

so if you just want to call `isPageComplete` on all your pages just call `super.canFinish`

Comment: okay, so it just behaves like a listener. I did not want to add logic that would not be executed on a page and then not be received on canFinish.